# Can't get ID token even with Auth code flow via Postman

Tags: postman, token, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to get ID token and Refresh token along with access token from Azure AD app via Postman by using below parameters:

```
GET
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id='myclient_id'
&client_secret='myclient_secret'
&grant_type=authorization_code
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
```

I am able to get the access token, but not sure why I am not getting ID token and Refresh token along with it.

Atfirst, I tried with client_credentials flow, but I came to know I have to use auth code flow or OpenID Connect in order to get those tokens.

So I shifted to auth code flow. But still I'm getting access token only:(

I have also enabled the below options in the Portal

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/wZjSfhv.png)]

What else settings are needed to get the tokens? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edited:**

I have given below API permissions:

[image]

Comment: Could you edit and include screenshot of the API permissions that you gave for application?

Comment: Please try and check granting openid and offline_access permissions for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **note** that, getting `ID token` and `Refresh token` along with access token depends on the **scope/API permissions** you grant to the application as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-2).

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and added scopes like below:***

[image]

After adding the **`openid`** and **`offline_access`** in the scope, I got all tokens successfully like below:

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/5ojwIDd.png)]